# Adding Refrigerator to Garage Door circuit

Tags: electrical-panel, garage, refrigerator, generator, service

I recently had a transfer switch installed for my generator. I'd like to add a basement refrigerator to the same breaker (in my service panel) as the garage door circuit.  This would allow the refrigerator to be include in the generator aided power in the event of a failure. Can this be done? Thanks

Comment: can you provide any load information about your garage door opener and the refrig?

Comment: Yes, is the breaker a 15A or a 20A breaker, and what are the nameplate ratings of the garage door opener and the fridge?

Comment: The breaker is 15 amp.

Comment: Draw from Refrigerator is 8.97, Garage Door draw is 3.25 amps

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Some more info would help us help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I think that code says that refrigerator should be on it's own circuit.  The notion was that a breaker trip was unlikely to result in spoiled food.  This is one of those places wehre slavish adherence to code is probably unneeded.